# Why can't I enter the letter z when editing in a ipynb file in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ipynb

I'm learning Python using VS Code. I've created an ipynb file and I'm having trouble typing the letter z.

It says "(Z) was pressed. Waiting for seconde key for chord" at the bottom of the picture, but I want to enter the letter z, how should I do it?

[image]

After pressing the z key, regardless of pressing any other key, it will display "The key combination (Z,XXX) is not a command."

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](/tour) Why do you want to 'enter' `Z`? Is it a valid shortcut/hotkey-combination? Please see [ask] and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar problem, and it was related to a keybinding issue. If it is the same case for you, then with the following steps you can resolve it.

1. Open Command Palette by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Select "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts" from the list.
3. On the Search bar, type "z" and check if keybindings are associated
4. You can either remove the keybinding or change it to a different key combination
5. In case there is no any problematic keybinding, then you can reset the keybindings to the default settings by clicking on the "..." button at the top right corner and select "Reset Keybindings".